What is the analogon of a ComponentError in Vaadin 24
in Vaadin 8, we had the so-called component errors, which I found to be very useful. (See Vaadin 8 docs 1) But how are we supposed to handle invalid input in Vaadin 24?

In Vaadin 24 you can use the Binder and then the validation error will be displayed by the input field.
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/components-binder

If you really want to roll your own (or can not use the Binder (see
other answer), the successor is the interface
HasValidation
which is in the class hierarchy for basically all the fields coming with
the core.
But this no longer has different "levels" of errors.  The field is
either valid or shows an "error string"; which is usually enough.
